# symfony 1.4 how to globally unset, hide or make read only a form widget?

Tags: php, forms, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

In my application I have a lot of modules and a lot of forms with their own widgets.
I have been trying to Globally '*unset*', '*hide*' or '*make read only*' a widget.
I know that its possible to do it for one widget in the *configure()* function of the form, but I am looking for a better solution, if possible in a global way. It could be a pain to change all module forms and keep track of them.
The thread could be a bit long but I think that its easy to understand the problem. Thank you so much if you have time to read it :)

I have built a simple news module with the Timestampable behavior to test some options but still none of them worked.

- table: `TbNews`
- columns:

  - `id` as primary key
  - `scontent` as a text field for saving the news content.
  - `created_at` as date time. (Timestampable behavior)
  - `updated_at` as date time. (Timestampable behavior)

**TbNews schema.yml:**

> ```
> TbNews:
>   connection: doctrine_master
>   tableName: tb_news
>   columns:
>     id:
>       type: integer(8)
>       fixed: false
>       unsigned: false
>       primary: true
>       autoincrement: true
>     scontent:
>       type: string(64000)
>       fixed: false
>       unsigned: false
>       primary: false
>       notnull: true
>       autoincrement: false
>   actAs:
>     Timestampable:
>       created:
>         name: created_at
>         type: timestamp
>         format: Y-m-d H:i:s
>         options:
>           notnull: false
>           required: false
>       updated:
>         name: updated_at
>         type: timestamp
>         format: Y-m-d H:i:s
>         options:
>           notnull: false
>           required: false
> ```

**TbNews updated_at in Form** 
(for the example, only wrote here the updated_at column):

> ```
> class TbNewsForm extends PluginTbNewsForm
> {
>   public function configure()
>   {
>       $this->setWidgets(array(
>           'updated_at'   => new sfWidgetFormDateTime(),
>       ));
>       $this->setValidators(array(
>         'updated_at'   => new sfValidatorDateTime(array('required' => false)),
>       ));
>   }
> }
> ```

**Template _form.php for TbNews updated_at**:
Tested a lot of options, manually rendering updated_at with: "echo $form['updated_at']" and without rendering it.

> ```
> <?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields(false) ?>
> ```

**Global tests with `update_at` column in:** *`lib/form/doctrine/BaseFormDoctrine.class.php`*:

- With `sfWidgetFormInputHidden()`, widget is not rendered in template.

  Tested unsetting it, without unsetting it, with setWidget, without it... all possible options but the field updated_at is not rendered in template. ( used renderHiddenFields() )

> ```
> abstract class BaseFormDoctrine extends sfFormDoctrine
> {
>   public function setup()
>   {
>       $value_updated_at = $this->getObject()->updated_at;
>       unset($this->widgetSchema['updated_at']);
>       unset($this->validatorSchema['updated_at']);
>       $this->widgetSchema['updated_at'] = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden();
>       $this->widgetSchema['updated_at']->setOption('is_hidden', 'true');
>       $this->widgetSchema['updated_at']->setOption('type', 'hidden'); 
>       $this->setDefault('updated_at', $value_updated_at);
>       $this->setWidget('updated_at', new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(array('value'=>$value_updated_at)));
>       //$this->setWidget('updated_at', $this->widgetSchema['updated_at']);
>   }
> }
> ```

- With read only:
  Added the field `updated_at` in the _form.php template, but its not shown as read only. Seems doesnt work with `sfWidgetFormDateTime`.

> ```
>   $this->widgetSchema['updated_at']->setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
> ```
>
> **Questions and thoughts:**
>   Probably `BaseFormDoctrine` is not the right way to global change a widget in all Form modules or there is probably something wrong in my tests. 
>   
>   As you may probably know, if we use the above code directly in the Form widget `TbNewsForm configure()`, we can easily change the widget from one type to another type, and individually render or hide it, and it works.

- But how can we implement it in a global way?
- Should it be necessary to change core code of symfony Doctrine?

Thank you so much if you could take time to read it, any comment or solution is welcome :)

Comment: Basically, you want `updated_at` & `created_at` to be hidden for all your form, right?

Comment: yes j0k, but affecting all modules which has created_at and updated_at fields.

Comment: Tested also only globally Unsetting those fields in BaseFormDoctrine, but NULL values are saved for created_at on update: UPDATE tb_news SET scontent = 'content3', created_at='', updated_at='2013-02-07 11:59:29' WHERE id='3'; Checked Listener code at C:\php5\PEAR\symfony\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Template\Listener\Timestampable.php but there is no easy solution.

Comment: I also have a lot of form classes in my projects, and I usually unset `created_at` & `updated_at` inside the configure. I prefer to see *what's going on* in the right form class instead of globally. What if you want to see these field in a backend app? Will you re-add them in the form class?

Comment: Yes, as you said thats the best way and If there is no other option I will have to do it manually for each form class. However it we find a working way to set it globally, it would be easy to add a module black/whitelist condition in the BaseFormDoctrine so that we know what modules form widgets are being filtered, filtering only some of them and only when we are not in backend.

Comment: @xtm You can do it in the base form, but why do you need this? You should use `$this->useFields()` in the `configure` method and just leave unneeded fields out.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `BaseFormDoctrine` class won't help you. The widgets for a form are set in the base class of the given form (`BaseTbNewsForm` in your case), so they will override any changes made in the `BaseFormDoctrine` class.

If you want to do the same operation for each form but don't want to rewrite the code in each class you can create a utility class and call it's method's in the forms' `configure()` function.

I don't think there is an option to do it globally without changing the Doctrine / Symfony internals (you would have to change the way in which base classes for you forms are generated).

Comment: Thank you Michal, your comment is really appretiated and its somehow what I thought. I will try some minor changes at the core and report them back soon, ty :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way which works, hovewer maybe not be the best solution since it involves modifing the source code of symfony. The function: ***setupInheritance()*** in the core file: ***sfFormDoctrine.class.php*** is called by all forms after setting widgets and validators, if we add the code there, our changes will work globally for all forms. 

In the example below, all widgets 'created_at' and 'updated_at' will be unset, and then set to be hidden:

```
 /**
   * Used in generated forms when models use inheritance.
   */
  protected function setupInheritance()
  {
    if (isset($this))
    {
      $oWidgetSchema = $this->getWidgetSchema();
      if (isset($oWidgetSchema))
      {
        $screatedcolumn = "created_at";
        $supdatedcolumn = "updated_at";

        //if ($this->isNew()) //we can add a check for new records

        //we can also add checks for frontend or backend
        //$request = sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest();
        //$this->url = 'http'.($request->isSecure() ? 's' : '').'://'. $request->getHost();
        //$suri_params = $request->getParameterHolder()->getAll();

        //set [created_at] as hidden field widget, and set its default value to the Original one before sending it to Timestampable.php Listener.
        if ( $oWidgetSchema->offsetExists($screatedcolumn) )
        {
          $value_created_at = $this->getObject()->created_at;
          unset($this->widgetSchema[$screatedcolumn]);
          $this->widgetSchema[$screatedcolumn] = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden();
          $this->widgetSchema[$screatedcolumn]->setOption('is_hidden', 'true');
          $this->widgetSchema[$screatedcolumn]->setOption('type', 'hidden');
          //unset($this->validatorSchema[$screatedcolumn]); //unset its validator to make sure values are not checked by default, optional.
          $this->setDefault($screatedcolumn, $value_created_at);
        }
        //set [updated_at] as hidden field widget, and set its default value to time() before sending it to Timestampable.php Listener.
        if ( $oWidgetSchema->offsetExists($supdatedcolumn) )
        {
          //$value_updated_at = $this->getObject()->updated_at;
          unset($this->widgetSchema[$supdatedcolumn]);
          $this->widgetSchema[$supdatedcolumn] = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden();
          $this->widgetSchema[$supdatedcolumn]->setOption('is_hidden', 'true');
          $this->widgetSchema[$supdatedcolumn]->setOption('type', 'hidden');
          //unset($this->validatorSchema[$supdatedcolumn]); //unset its validator to make sure values are not checked by default, optional.
          $this->setDefault($supdatedcolumn, time());
        }
      }
    }
```